# Handle Tensor in loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a feature map and some coordinate
I want to do something like below
crop the data from feature map by the coordinate
Then do `argmax`, `concat`(or `stack`?)
How can I do this in Tensorflow?

```
# num_coor is Not fixed, but fixed is ok!
# it defined before run
num_coor = 4
feature_map = np.transpose(np.reshape(np.arange(100*100*3), (3, 100, 100)), [1, 2, 0])
x_coor = np.array([[0, 20, 40, 60],
                   [15, 35, 55, 75]])  # shape(?, num_coor)
y_coor = np.array([[0, 20, 40, 60],
                   [15, 35, 55, 75]])  # shape(?, num_coor)
crop = []

for batch in xrange(x_coor.shape[0]):
    temp1 = []
    for i in xrange(num_coor - 1):
        temp2 = []
        for j in xrange(num_coor - 1):
            x1 = x_coor[batch, j]
            y1 = y_coor[batch, i]
            x2 = x_coor[batch, j + 1]
            y2 = y_coor[batch, i + 1]

            # slice by coordinate and len(slice_map) is depth
            slice_map = [feature_map[x1:x2, y1:y2, c] for c in xrange(feature_map.shape[2])]
            resmax = [np.amax(slice_map[c]) for c in xrange(len(slice_map))]
            resmax = np.reshape(np.array(resmax), (1, 1, feature_map.shape[2]))
            temp2.append(resmax)
        temp1.append(np.vstack(temp2))
    temp_arr = np.concatenate(temp1, axis=1)
    crop.append(np.array(temp_arr))

crop = np.array(crop) # (2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Four coordinate in x,y can constitute 9 bins
I want to do max pool in each bin and each channel
so that I can get pool result, shape is `(2, 3, 3, 3) # (2, h, w, c)` in this case

[image]

I think I can use `tf.while_loop` to do this
But I don't know how to access external tensor and return the result
I did a small test, it seem doesn't access external tensor

```
i = tf.constant(0)
first_coor = x_coor[i, :]
while_cond = lambda i, _: tf.less(i, 5)

def body(i, the_coor):
    # print every loop
    i = i + 1
    i = tf.Print(i, [i], 'i is :') 
    i = i + 0

    # Never print!!
    coor = x_coor
    coor = tf.Print(coor, [coor], 'coor is :') 
    coor = coor + 0

    # print every loop
    the_coor = tf.Print(the_coor, [the_coor], 'the_coor is :')
    the_coor = the_coor + 0
    return i, the_coor

r = tf.while_loop(while_cond, body, [i, first_coor])
```

Comment: Are your coordinates the same within the batch? i.e. you just want to extract information from the feature map?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov sorry for reply late. No, the coordinates are different at each batch(i.e. 2), but the number of coordinate is fixed (i.e. 4 coordinates in x and y axis), and yes I want to extract information from the feature map

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a regular for loop in this case (note how the lambda was able to access an external tensor, `feature_map` in this case):

```
batch_feature_map_max_fn = lambda xy : tf.reduce_max(feature_map[xy[0]:xy[1], xy[2]:xy[3], -1])

crop = []
for j in range(num_coor-1):
    x1 = x_coor[:, j]
    x2 = x_coor[:, j+1]
    y1 = y_coor[:, j]
    y2 = y_coor[:, j+1]

    temp = tf.map_fn(fn, [x1,x2,y1,y2], dtype=tf.float32)

    crop.append(temp)

crop = tf.pack(crop, axis=1)
```

As for the `tf.while_loop`, I believe you will be able to access all tensors that you are passing in the `loop_vars` argument. You can just return the extra tensors without any changes. I am not sure `tf.while_loop` is really suitable in this case, though.

Comment: Thanks your answer, I'm so sorry that I just figure out my example code is wrong, I draw a picture, could you please see it again?